# Xamarin Forms Converter being called on page disappearing?

Tags: xamarin.forms, converters

```xml
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
    Text="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource localTimeConverter}, StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}'}"
    LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
    FontSize="16"
    Style="{DynamicResource FieldLabel}"/>
```

I have the above Xaml and the below Converter:

```cs
public class UtcToLocalDateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((DateTime)value).ToLocalTime();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

However the Converter is not being called when the page starts instead it gets called when navigating away from the page. I add a break point in the convert method and that's when the method is being called. This is confusing!?

Please can someone offer some help?

Comment: The converter is being called whenever the binded value changes. Set a breakpoint to Date property and see in the stack trace where is it coming from.

Comment: The converter always called when property is changed

Comment: Yes, however the converter should get called when the page loads initially but, in my case the converter is not being called at that time - weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops ! This was my bad.

I was adding the converter into the SelectedItemTemplate of the ListView instead of the ItemTemplate of the ListView. Thats why the converter never got called. All fixed now.

Comment: That's great ! Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people :)